# Efficient way of displaying multiple lists

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to build a list view exactly like the one which you can see in the image. I have different categories and then relevant data according to that category. I tried one option which was having multiple list views but the thing is that my data is dynamically coming through an API. Is this a single list view with section headers or is it something else? Just need the proper direction to what should I look for such a thing.

[image: First Flavor Option][image: Second Flavor Option][image: Third Flavor Option]

Comment: try delegate adapters with recycler view. This is what you are looking for

Comment: I'd go for an ExpandableListView.

Comment: @ivanovd422 I will have a look at it

Comment: @Fantômas but the question is what if we want to implement it this way?

Comment: Then it would be a bad design

Comment: @Fantômas Thanks for the advice. The screenshots i posted are from Door Dash app so it means they have done a bad job?

Comment: Well... 3 ListViews one after another, for me, is an **awful** design. You're forced to scroll and scroll and scroll...

Comment: @Fantômas Good point. Will consider this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can be made using a single RecyclerView/ListView and appending the list when the previous ends.

```
public void addData(List<CustomSummary> add) {
        if (add!=null) {
            items.addAll(add);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Add this code in adapter and call it when reached bottom of the list.

Comment: I am currently implementing a recyclerview and trying this.